Puppeteer Cluster Error: "Unable to launch browser, error message: kill EACCES" on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble
I'm facing an issue while trying to launch a Puppeteer Cluster on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble. The error message I get is:
Error creating puppeteer cluster Unable to launch browser, error message: kill EACCES

I have tried the following steps:

Installed chromium multiple times and verified the path.
Added the required dependencies:
libaacs0 libass9 libavcodec60 libavformat60 libavutil58 libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libchromaprint1 libcjson1 libcodec2-1.2 libgfortran5 libgme0 libgsm1 liblapack3
liblilv-0-0 libmbedcrypto7t64 libmysofa1 libnorm1t64 libopenmpt0t64 liboss4-salsa2 libpgm-5.3-0t64 libplacebo338 libpocketsphinx3 libpostproc57 librabbitmq4 librist4
librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libsphinxbase3t64 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.5-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample4 libswscale7 libudfread0
libunibreak5 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvpl2 libx265-199 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzix-0-0 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0t64 mesa-vdpau-drivers pocketsphinx-en-us
vdpau-driver-all


Set the executablePath to /snap/bin/chromium in my Puppeteer options.
Made the Chromium binary executable using:
chmod +x /snap/bin/chromium


Removed package-lock.json and reinstalled all dependencies.

Here is my Puppeteer setup code:
const getPuppeteerInstance = async () => {
  try {
    let options = {
      headless: true,
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      ],
      executablePath: process.env.CHROMIUM_PATH || "/snap/bin/chromium",
    };

    let browserInstance = await Cluster.launch({
      concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
      maxConcurrency: 10,
      puppeteerOptions: options,
      timeout: 10000000,
    });
    return browserInstance;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating puppeteer cluster", error.message);
  }
};

Despite these efforts, I’m still getting the kill EACCES error. How can I fix this issue?
Additional Details:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 Noble
Puppeteer version: "puppeteer": "^21.8.0",
"puppeteer-cluster": "^0.23.0",
"puppeteer-core": "^13.0.1",
Node.js version:18
Chromium installed via Snap: /snap/bin/chromium

What am I missing, or are there alternative steps to debug this issue?
